# How does the Iterator::collect function work?

Tags: rust, iterator, documentation, collect

I am trying to understand the full capabilities of `collect` function by going through [some documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#provided-methods). I am running into some challenges, specifically in the last example quoted on the page (also listed below, with my comments inline)

```
let results = [Ok(1), Err("nope"), Ok(3), Err("bad")];

let result: Result<Vec<_>, &str> = results.iter().cloned().collect();

// gives us the first error <-- Point 1
assert_eq!(Err("nope"), result);

let results = [Ok(1), Ok(3)];

let result: Result<Vec<_>, &str> = results.iter().cloned().collect();

// gives us the list of answers
assert_eq!(Ok(vec![1, 3]), result);
```

I followed up this code with some of my own (shown below)

```
let results: [std::result::Result<i32, &str>; 2] = [Err("nope"), Err("bad")];

let result: Vec<Result<i32, &str>> = results.iter().cloned().collect();

// The following prints <-- Point 2
// "nope"
// "bad"
for x in result{
    println!("{:?}", x.unwrap_err());
}
```

Looking at the implementation of [the `FromIterator` trait on the `Result` struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/result.rs.html#283-288), we see that it mentions that "Takes each element in the `Iterator`: if it is an `Err`, no further elements are taken, and the `Err` is returned. Should no `Err` occur, a container with the values of each `Result` is returned.

This explanation is in line with the result that is seen at Point 1 but doesn't seem to work with Point 2. In point 2 I was expecting only "nope" to be printed instead of both values.

Hence, I am trying to understand where this (selective) conversion is happening and running into a challenge.

If we look at the method definition itself we see the following.

```
#[inline]
fn from_iter<I: IntoIterator<Item=Result<A, E>>>(iter: I) -> Result<V, E> {
    // FIXME(#11084): This could be replaced with Iterator::scan when this
    // performance bug is closed.

    iter::process_results(iter.into_iter(), |i| i.collect())
}
```

It shows that the `into_iter()` method is being called on the iterator. Searching for `into_iter` gives two implementations

````
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
impl<T, E> IntoIterator for Result<T, E> {
    type Item = T;
    type IntoIter = IntoIter<T>;

    /// Returns a consuming iterator over the possibly contained value.
    ///
    /// The iterator yields one value if the result is [`Result::Ok`], otherwise none.
    ///
    /// # Examples
    ///
    /// Basic usage:
    ///
    /// ```
    /// let x: Result<u32, &str> = Ok(5);
    /// let v: Vec<u32> = x.into_iter().collect();
    /// assert_eq!(v, [5]);
    ///
    /// let x: Result<u32, &str> = Err("nothing!");
    /// let v: Vec<u32> = x.into_iter().collect();
    /// assert_eq!(v, []);
    /// ```
    #[inline]
    fn into_iter(self) -> IntoIter<T> {
        IntoIter { inner: self.ok() }
    }
}

#[stable(since = "1.4.0", feature = "result_iter")]
impl<'a, T, E> IntoIterator for &'a Result<T, E> {
    type Item = &'a T;
    type IntoIter = Iter<'a, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Iter<'a, T> {
        self.iter()
    }
}
````

However, in my limited understanding of the language none seem to be able to explain what the documentation says as well as what is happening in Point 2.

Could someone please explain how this is working or point me to the right place in source where such selection logic is implemented?

What I want to understand is not why we get all values in a vector and only one in the result, but a. where is the code/logic to select the first `Err` from a list of values and b. why are multiple `Err` values selected when the result is collected in a list (when according to the documentation it should be only the first `Err` value)

Comment: `from_iter` is doing more than just calling `into_iter()`. Did you look up the definition of `iter::process_results`?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley can you point me to the implementation for process_results ?

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libcore/iter/adapters/mod.rs#L2580

Answer (score 10):

In this example

```rust
let result: Vec<Result<i32, &str>> = results.iter().cloned().collect();
```

you do not collect into a `Result`, but into a `Vec`, hence all values are collected, untouched. This is expected from `Vec`.

This is fundamentally different from

```rust
let result: Result<Vec<_>, &str> = results.iter().cloned().collect();
```

where you collect into a `Result`, which does filter elements depending on whether an `Err` is found or not. This comes from [`impl<A, E, V> FromIterator<Result<A, E>> for Result<V, E> where V: FromIterator<A>,`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#impl-FromIterator%3CResult%3CA%2C%20E%3E%3E).

Comment: Thanks, but what I want to understand is not why we get all values in a vector and only one in the result, but a. where is the code/logic to select the first Err from a list of values and b. why are multiple Err values selected when the result is collected in a list (when according to the documentation it should be only the first Err value). I will also modify the question to make that clear.

Comment: @LateNighter "what I want to understand is not why we get all values in a vector and only one in the result," how many are you inside you ?

Answer (score 4):

[`Iterator::collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) is defined as:

```rust
fn collect<B: FromIterator<Self::Item>>(self) -> B
where
    Self: Sized,
{
    FromIterator::from_iter(self)
}
```

All of the interesting implementation is done via the [`FromIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html) trait. Every type can choose how to implement this trait as makes sense.

The implementation for `Result` and `Vec` are both optimized and abstracted, so it's not trivial to point to one line of code and say "here's where it is".

#### `Result`

This calls `iter::process_results`, an internal helper method for "lifting" an iterator of `Result`s (you can see something similar in [`Itertools::process_results`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/fn.process_results.html)). If any `Result::Err` is encountered, then the iteration stops with that error. Otherwise, the closure is executed with an iterator containing only the success values. The closure calls `Iterator::collect` on the inner collection type, producing a `Vec` of the successful values.

#### `Vec`

This performs some internal specialization indirection via the `SpecFromIter` helper trait. Following through all of that, you'll see that an empty `Vec` is created and then [`extend`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Extend.html#tymethod.extend)ed with all of the items in the iterator.