# Intersection of two BTreeSet objects in Rust

Tags: rust, collections, iterator, set-intersection

I can't figure out how to take two BTreeSet objects and create a new, owned, BTreeSet from the intersection operation.

Here is a Minimal Example:

```
use std::collections::BTreeSet;

fn test() -> BTreeSet<u64> {
    let mut s1 = BTreeSet::new();
    let mut s2 = BTreeSet::new();

    s1.insert(1u64);
    s2.insert(2u64);

    let s_out = s1.intersection(&s2);

    return s_out; // this does not work
}
```

The reason this does not work appears to be because `intersection` creates an iterator, which is lazy evaluated. I want to create a new "owned" object / BTreeSet from the existing two BTreeSets.

How do I do that?

[`intersection`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeSet.html#method.intersection) returns some other kind of object which is an [`Intersection`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/btree_set/struct.Intersection.html) object. The intended purpose is presumably so that it can be lazy-evaluated. (See docs.)

Comment: If you read the docs you can strike the presumably, `Intersection` is documented to be a "lazy iterator".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution is fairly trivial and requires this. The type hints are optional.

```
let s_out = s1.intersection(&s2);

s_out.cloned().collect::<BTreeSet<u64>>();
```

or

```
let s_out = s1.intersection(&s2);

s_out.cloned().collect();
```

## How it works:

`s_out` is an iterator type. It provides lazy-evaluation. What this means is that `s_out` is **not** another `BTreeSet`. It does not have the ownership semantics which I intended.

As described in the Question, what I wanted to do was produce a new, owned, `BTreeSet`.

In order to achieve this, we have to call `collect` on the iterator. That will iterate over all the elements, and "collect" them into a new `std::collection` type. In this case I explicitly specified `BTreeSet`, but that may not be required if the type can be inferred from elsewhere in the code...

The reason `cloned` is required is otherwise we obtain a BTreeSet of references to existing things, rather than "owned" clones of those things.

How exactly ownership behaves is dependent on what types you are working with and whether `Copy` or `Clone` are derived for those types.

At this point, the answer becomes a discussion or Rust ownership semantics, so the reader is encouraged to find references for this elsewhere...

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged, please explain why this solves the problme instead of just pasting some code.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515668/how-does-the-iteratorcollect-function-work and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68607334/how-does-rust-collect-create-different-collections-generically